# Install Neo4J's APOC in my Structr application

Tags: structr

In Structr v.3.0.x I would like to use an APOC procedure in my cypher query to output the data I need to build a D3 tree on a page.
Please could you tell me how to install APOC in my Structr application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to use APOC with Structr is to install Neo4j on its own on your machine with APOC as a plugin (see [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) for more information)

Then you can configure Structr to connect to Neo4j (just follow [these](https://support.structr.com/article/456) instuctions) and use any APOC procedures you like